# Find the closest element by class from previous all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html

```
<ul>
    <li class='header_1 header_class'>Header 1</li>
    <li class='ooption_1 option_class'>OPTION 1</li>
    <li class='ooption_2 option_class'>OPTION 2</li>
    <li class='ooption_3 option_class'>OPTION 3</li>
    <li class='header_2 header_class'>Header 2</li>
    <li class='ooption_4 option_class'>OPTION 4</li>
    <li class='ooption_5 option_class'>OPTION 5</li>
    <li class='ooption_6 option_class'>OPTION 6</li>
    <li class='header_3 header_class'>Header 3</li>
    <li class='ooption_7 option_class'>OPTION 7</li>
    <li class='ooption_8 option_class'>OPTION 8</li>
    <li class='ooption_9 option_class'>OPTION 9</li>
</ul>
```

If OPTION 1 is clicked then text 'Header 1' should be alerted,if OPTION 4 is clicked then text 'Header 2' should be alerted.Please tell jquery function to do this.

Comment: can you show, what you tried till now, put it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Where are you stuck? jQuery's [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) are pretty well-documented.

Comment: i tried but unable to get the jquery functions for this

Comment: @Rex show us what you have tried

Comment: It is better to put `options` as child of `header`. Then use CSS to set look as you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.prevAll()` to select preceding siblings matching a selector.

```
alert($(this).prevAll(".header_class").first().text());
```

Comment: works well http://jsfiddle.net/CZXkq/

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/).

```
jQuery('.option_class').click(function () {
    var theText = jQuery(this).prevAll('.header_class').first().text();
    alert(theText);
});
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/FeHb9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
  $('li[class^=ooption]').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $(this).prevAll('.header_class').eq(0).text() );
  });
});
```